# Get When User Click On Any Key In Windows Forms When The WinForms Are Not Active

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

so, its abit hard to expline my problem here.

i am have a Windows Forms App that when you click a `button` shes `KeyPressing` in your keybord so that you enter into a website.

i have no idea how can i do that when my user(me) clicked on F9 or any key that i chose will stop it.

REMEMEBER:
The windows form is in the backgournd,i am in the webiste.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't understand what "click on a key" means but I assume you mean "press a key"...

IF so then you can use the code + method show here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx